A simple formula to interpolate (almost) any sequence?
In the old paper from Schröder named Ueber iterirte Functionen (available here and famous for introducing what is known as Schröder's equation), I encountered this formula (page 311)
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom xn \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk (-1)^{n-k} f(k).
$$
If the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb N$, then the formula has a straightforward proof. (hint: $\binom{x}{n}\binom{n}{k} = \binom{x}{k}\binom{x-k}{n-k}$). But nothing prevent us from evaluating the following for $x \in \mathbb R$, as the binomial coefficient has a the known generalization $\binom{x}{n} = x (x-1) \cdots (x-n+1)/n!$.
It is provable, by algebraic manipulations, that if $f$ is a polynomial, then the sum is finite and equals the polynomial $f(x)$ for all $x$. In that case, it is like a simplifying special case of the Lagrange interpolation where the sampling points are the integers $\{0, \ldots, \deg f\}$. If $f(k) = a^k$, then we retrieve $a^x$ with the binomial theorem, but it converges only for $|a-1| < 1$. So it looks like the faster the function grows at the start, the less it converges at the end. A first example of a case where it doesn't converge is $f(k) = k!$, though, I found a simple workaround, that seems to imply the following conjecture, for $x \geq 0$:
$$
\Gamma(x+1) = \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom xn \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk (-1)^{n-k} (k!)^{\frac1{k+1}}\right)^{x+1}.
$$
Explicitly, the workaround consists of slowing down the factorial by applying a function, then apply the inverse function at the end. The graphs are definitly similar.
I tried to interpolate the Mobiüs function, but it seems this formula is also subject to Runge's phenomenon.
Question: Does anyone has ever encountered these formulas? I couldn't find anything on it and Schröder only used this for a special case.
